# mvel equals operator doesn't work as expected with char operand

Tags: java, type-conversion, mvel

Is mvel equals operator doesn't work as expected with char operand or am I missing something?
It throws NumberFormatException: For input string: "E" I would expect false in system output.
Is there any 'configuration option' for MVEL that fits here? Or any idea how to make lovely workaround?
Please note, I can't change parameters as they are composed at runtime.

```
    System.out.println(MVEL.eval("arg1 == arg2", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("arg1", "5");
        put("arg2", 'E');
    }}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected with String operand, so the best workaround I came up with is this

```
arg1 == arg2.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `E` as a character, not a string. If you want it as a string then make it a string. They're not even the same type, let alone the same value.

Comment: yeah, the whole point is in automatic type conversion, which works fine in most cases but with string where there is number inside and the char with not a number. This is a bug of MVEL and should be fixed to return false, not unwind the stack.